# Does the IOT Edge 1.4 inside EFLOW 1.4 automatically use the DigiCert Global G2 Root Cert for TLS to IOT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-iot-tls-critical-changes-are-almost-here-and-why-you/ba-p/2393169

Regarding the upcoming Azure IoT Hub Server Certificate Migration to DigiCert Global G2 Root, I have a few questions.
Does the IOT Edge 1.4 inside EFLOW 1.4 automatically use the DigiCert Global G2 Root Cert for TLS to IOT Hub?
How can I check to insure DigiCert is in place?
How do I install my corporate DigiCert certificate into IOT Edge inside EFLOW?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

No it won't *automatically* use the DigiCert Global G2 root. That isn't how TLS works. The server, the IoT hub in the case, will send the client a certificate chain. The topmost certificate in the chain will be signed by a root certificate. IoT hub topmost certificates will be signed by either the Baltimore CyberTrust Root or the DigiCert Global Root G2. This migration to the latter is in progress. As long as the topmost certifcate is signed by a root certificate that is in the trusted root store then the Eflow will be able to verify the authenticity of the server. In this case both of those certificates are trusted by the Eflow virtual machine so you don't need to do anything for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome ! thank you Mark

```
$ sudo find . -name ca-certificates.crt
 ./etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 ./snap/core20/1828/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 ./snap/core/14946/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

$ openssl storeutl -text -noout -certs /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep -i " subject.*digicert global root g2"

    Subject: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root G2
```

Answer (score -1):

You will find a `config.yaml` file under the directory `/etc/iotedge` inside your Eflow. The file has a section that points to the certificates utilized by the IoT Edge runtime. Please refer to the below image for reference

[image]

After you have the new certificates, you can copy them locally onto Eflow using the `scp` command and refer the certificate path in the `config.yaml` file.

Restart your IoT Edge using `sudo systemctl restart iotedge` to make sure the Eflow uses the latest certificates.

Comment: The above answer is incorrect. Let's start with the fact that a directory called /etc/iotedge does not even exist on an EFlow install. The config format is pre Edge version 1.2 and those particular fields referenced have nothing to do with trusting the DigiCert Global Root G2.

Comment: Sounds like the TLS cert config lives in the Eflow virtual machine ie at OS level ?  Where in the OS is the cert config located ?

Comment: Sample dump:   125399276383040:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
subject=C = US, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06    ..........subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Assured ID Root G2

Comment: Above continued:  subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Assured ID Root G3
subject=C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root
subject=C = US, O = "DigiCert, Inc.", CN = DigiCert ECC P384 Root G5 ....

Comment: You can find the trusted cert at /etc/pki/tls/certs. That contains three certificate bundles. I don't know if it uses all of them as trusted roots but all three contain the DigiCert Global Root G2. You can see this with the command:
`openssl storeutl -text -noout -certs ca-certificates.crt | grep -i "
subject.*digicert global root g2"`

Comment: @MarkRadbourne Ok so I will look at the certs that live in the EFLOW VM ie the VM where IOT edge lives.